# Finding the item that appears odd number of times

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to solve a problem on Codewars that involves finding the item of an array that appears an odd number of times. The solution I have passes 3 tests but fails 3 others.

```
function findOdd(A) {
  //happy coding!
  let odd = "";
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
     for (let j = 0; j < A.length; j++){
      if (A[i] === A[j] ){
        count++;
        }
       if (count %2 != 0){
         odd = A[i];
       }
    } 
  }
  return odd;
}
```

These are the test cases that fail

```
A1 =  [ 1, 1, 2, -2, 5, 2, 4, 4, -1, -2, 5 ]

n1 =  -1

A2 =  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]

n2 =  10

A3 =  [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 10, 10 ]

n3 =  1
```

and these are the test cases that pass

```
A4 =  [ 20, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 20, 4, -1, -2, 5 ]

n4 =  5

A5 =  [ 20, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 20, 4, 5 ]

n5 =  5

A6 =  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]

n6 =  10
```

where A1 - A6 are the input arrays and n1 - n6 are the expected outcomes

Comment: Move the if condition count % 2 out of the second for loop and put it below second for loop

Comment: Make an object, count up the occurrences, find the odd.

Comment: Also, initialize count = 0; above second for loop and I assume you can also break once you find an odd number.

Comment: Your function will return an empty string if it fails to find an odd count. That's probably not ideal. Your algorithm, after correcting, is also very inefficient.

Comment: `+(Object.entries([ 1, 1, 2, -2, 5, 2, 4, 4, -1, -2, 5 ].reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = (o[k] || 0) + 1, o), {})).find(([num, count]) => count % 2) || [])[0]`

Comment: @nice_dev Both of your suggestions worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can generate a new object that contains the duplicated count of the each element.

Based on that object, you can find the element which has got odd duplicates in an array.

```js
function findOdd(A) {
  const countArr = A.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur] ? acc[cur] ++ : acc[cur] = 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
  const odd = Object.keys(countArr).find((key) => countArr[key] % 2);
  return +odd;
}

console.log('n1 = ', findOdd([1, 1, 2, -2, 5, 2, 4, 4, -1, -2, 5]));
console.log('n2 = ', findOdd([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
console.log('n3 = ', findOdd([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 10, 10]));
console.log('n4 = ', findOdd([20, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 20, 4, -1, -2, 5]));
console.log('n5 = ', findOdd([20, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 20, 4, 5]));
console.log('n6 = ', findOdd([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
```